# Windows 10 not finding drivers booting from USB?

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade

I used Rufus to create a bootable Windows 10 USB from the ISO I got from Microsoft's website. When I boot my laptop into it, it says there is a media driver missing and I can't continue the installation. It doesn't crash, it just disables the 'Next' button until I give it a driver (which I don't have).

Comment: which SATA controller do you have?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I'm doing it on a Dell Inspiron 15R SE if that helps.

Comment: I have the same laptop and I can boot Win10 (WinToGo from a SSD attached via USB3.0) without issue.

Comment: It's fixed now, I just created and used an Installation Media instead of using the ISO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue multiple times since I posted this question 2 years ago. It seems to be caused by a faulty ISO. Another possible solution is to find your AHCI drivers on another computer and install them too.